# AG-Grid SSRM, Blank Page Issue After Visiting the Last Page

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm facing an issue where Ag-Grid shows a blank page after visiting the last page.

Steps to Reproduce

1. First load the ag-grid it will show the first page
2. Go to the last page, which will load correctly
3. Then come back to the first page, which will load as intended
4. But when the user tries to load the second page it shows blank

Please let me know how to resolve this issue

**AG-Grid Version: 29.3.4**

[Plunker to Reproduce](https://plnkr.co/edit/sx8QwMHbDzReS5EH)

Here is a sample code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ColDef,
  GridReadyEvent,
  IServerSideDatasource,
  RowModelType,
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { IOlympicData } from './interfaces';

declare var FakeServer: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular> `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'id', maxWidth: 75 },
    { field: 'athlete', minWidth: 190 },
    { field: 'age' },
    { field: 'year' },
    { field: 'gold' },
    { field: 'silver' },
    { field: 'bronze' },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 90,
    resizable: true,
  };
  public rowModelType: RowModelType = 'serverSide';
  public paginationPageSize = 10;
  public cacheBlockSize = 10;
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    this.http
      .get<IOlympicData[]>(
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // add id to data
        var idSequence = 1;
        data.forEach(function (item: any) {
          item.id = idSequence++;
        });
        // setup the fake server with entire dataset
        var fakeServer = new FakeServer(data);
        // create datasource with a reference to the fake server
        var datasource = getServerSideDatasource(fakeServer);
        // register the datasource with the grid
        params.api!.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
      });
  }
}

function getServerSideDatasource(server: any): IServerSideDatasource {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
      var response = server.getData(params.request);
      // adding delay to simulate real server call
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.success) {
          // call the success callback
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rows,
            rowCount: response.lastRow,
          });
        } else {
          // inform the grid request failed
          params.fail();
        }
      }, 200);
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: @mr_muscle It seems the issue was with Ag-Grid official package of that particular version, If you upgrade or downgrade the version, it works fine.